# How can multiple audio files be played in sequence?

Tags: c#, .net

In my C# application, I need to play multiple audio files ([WAV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WAV) and [MP3](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MP3)) one after the other.
How can I accomplish that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CodeProject have several examples that shows how to play audio. Once you get the hang of that playing multiple files after each other should be easy.

1. [A low-level audio player in C#](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/audio-video/cswavplay.aspx)
2. [Playing .wav files using C#](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/audio-video/PlaySounds1.aspx)
3. [Audio Player using winmm.dll and WPL File](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/audio-video/Audio_Player__with_Winmm.aspx)
4. [A simple class to allow you to play Wavs in C#](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/audio-video/tonysound.aspx)

I find that working directly with winmm.dll is pretty easy. My recomendation is to start with example 3

Comment: thanks, Nifle.
I took a look at example 3. and it wouldn't work with .wav files, would only work with .mp3, so I modified the MCI commands to fit my needs. and to achieve the fact that it would play the whole list one song after another, I added the "notify" feature and it worked out great. i'm happy i could solve my problem. it shows that somehow, as time passes, I'm learning more.
Thanks again.

Cheers !

Answer (score 1):

Example Using NAudio for WAV files

```
 private List<string> wavlist = new List<string>();
 wavlist.Add("c:\\1.wav");
 wavlist.Add("c:\\2.wav");
 foreach(string file  in wavlist)
 {
      AudioFileReader audio = new AudioFileReader(file);
      audio.Volume = 1;
      IWavePlayer player = new WaveOut(WaveCallbackInfo.FunctionCallback());
      player.Init(audio);
      player.Play();
      System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(audio.TotalTime);
      player.Stop();
      player.Dispose();
      audio.Dispose();
      player = null;
      audio = null;
  }
```